# Distinguishing between numeric only strings and otherwise

Tags: r, string, function, character, logical-operators

I want to make a logical test to distinguish between string vectors that except `":"` are made of only numbers (like vector `B`) AND string vectors that except `":"` are NOT made of only numbers (like vector `A`).

The name of this logical test can be `is_num_vec` (*see below*). Is this possible in R?

```
A = c("prof2:wcf_type2", "prof2:wcf_type3", "1", "c.f_.")
B = c("2:2", "2:3", "1", "2")


is_num_vec <- function(vec){

# Your solution

}

#### EXPECTED OUTPUT:
 is_num_vec(A)
> [1]  FALSE

 is_num_vec(B)
> [1]  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple solution that might fit your purpose:

First remove `:` from `vec`, then use `grepl()` to test whether all elements in `vec` are numbers only `^[0-9]{1,}$`. Use `all()` to test whether all logical values are `TRUE`.

```
is_num_vec <- function(vec){
  all(grepl("^[0-9]{1,}$", gsub(":", "", vec)))
}

is_num_vec(A)
[1] FALSE

is_num_vec(B)
[1] TRUE

is_num_vec("5a3")
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you both, well I upvoted both and both answers are correct. I would like to know what's the difference between the two approaches so I can accept one.

Comment: In my approach, multiple colons still works fine. In @Tim Biegeleisen's approach, more than 1 colon will return `FALSE`

Comment: Super helpful! Bingo

Comment: Multiple colons is not an edge case mentioned nor one which needs to be covered here.

Comment: I think Tim's answer does handle multiple colon anyway, just try it with: `A = c("prof2:wcf_type2:C", "prof2:wcf_type3","1","cf");
B = c("2:2:1", "2:3", "1", "2")`

Comment: @rnorouzian I mean it does not work for something like `5235:::::53`

Comment: Oh, I see, that's not what is expected in my case though. Anyway thank you both.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Because when I'm thinking about the solution, this statement: "string vectors that except ":" are made of only numbers" catches my mind first, therefore I immediately think of cases such as `5235:::::53`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one base approach using `sum()` with `grepl()`:

```r
is_num_vec <- function(vec) {
    return(sum(grepl("^\\d+(?::\\d+)*$", vec)) == length(vec))
}

is_num_vec(A)  # [1] FALSE
is_num_vec(B)  # [1] TRUE
```

**Data:**

```
A <- c("prof2:wcf_type2", "prof2:wcf_type3", "1", "c.f_.")
B <- c("2:2", "2:3", "1", "2")
```

Comment: My answer explicitly tries to match `1:2:3...`, i.e. a colon separated list of numbers.  The other answer removes colon and then asserts that what remains is all digit characters.  They both work, it is your choice what to accept.